# Error code nodejs : unhandledpromiserejectionwarning

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to make a text to speech recording sent via Facebook chat bot, but sometimes received and sometimes not received. How to fix that?
Source code:

```js
module.exports.config = {
  name: "sayv2",
  version: "1.0.1",
  hasPermssion: 0,
  credits: "NTKhang",
  description: "sing <nội dung>",
  commandCategory: "audio",
  usages: "sing <nội dung>, (sử dụng api fbvn)",
  cooldowns: 0,
};

module.exports.run = async ({ event, api, args }) => {
  const axios = require("axios");
  const fs = require("fs-extra");

  var response = (
    await axios.get(
      encodeURI(`https://fbvn.online/API/?apicualeanhtruong=${args.join(" ")}`)
    )
  ).data;

  if (response.endsWith("1")) {
    response = response.slice(0, response.length - 1);
  }

  response = JSON.parse(response);

  var getSound = (
    await axios.get(response.async, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
  ).data;
  const path = __dirname + "/cache/tts.mp3";

  fs.writeFileSync(path, Buffer.from(getSound));

  api.sendMessage(
    { attachment: fs.createReadStream(path) },
    event.threadID,
    () => fs.unlinkSync(path),
    event.messageID
  );
};
```

Photo error:

[image]

Please help me fix it to a complete code.

Comment: it's still showing the same error and it's not responding to the mp3 file from the api :(

Comment: Please update the title to something that is more specific about the problem you're facing

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that, you have a unhandled `error` being thrown in your `async` code which needs to be handled. You can handle this by just introducing a `try/catch` block in your `async` code as shown below:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

module.exports.run = async ({ event, api, args }) => {
  try {
    var response = (
      await axios.get(
        encodeURI(
          `https://fbvn.online/API/?apicualeanhtruong=${args.join(" ")}`
        )
      )
    ).data;
    if (response.endsWith("1"))
      response = response.slice(0, response.length - 1);
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    var getSound = (
      await axios.get(response.async, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
    ).data;
    const path = __dirname + "/cache/tts.mp3";
    fs.writeFileSync(path, Buffer.from(getSound));
    api.sendMessage(
      { attachment: fs.createReadStream(path) },
      event.threadID,
      () => fs.unlinkSync(path),
      event.messageID
    );
  } catch (error) {
      // Try to use a logger to log errors to a file if possible. 
      // logger.error(error);
      console.error(error)
  }
};
```

**P.S**: This will handle the error exception, and will tell you the exact cause of the error. You then need to make changes to your logic to correct your code so that there are no such errors in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try catch` block inside of the async function. So that if the axios request is rejected it will throw an Error which could be caught in `catch`
block.

Comment: or you can use process.on('unhandledRejection') to catch all of the promise rejection errors

Comment: please help me write a complete source code :((

Comment: Yes but that image attached above clearly says that error originates from inside of that async function.